# What is wrong here with these conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
user = input()

if (user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) > (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('happy')

elif (user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) < (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('sad')

elif (user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) == (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('unsure')

else:
    print('none')
```

It supposed to print 'none' when I write anything that does not include :-) or :-( but it prints 'unsure' everytime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with those if-statetments. First is that `(user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) > (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")`won't compare number of smiley faces to sad faces. It will first evaluate `user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")` which would be *True* if there is at least one smiley face or *False* if there is none. Then it would evaluate sad faces and then compare those results. Easiest workaround would be to sum those counts, something like this:

```
if (user.count(":-)") + user.count(" :-) ")) > (user.count(":-(") + user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('happy')
...
```

Second problem is that you last *elif* would result in *True* when there is no smiley or sad faces because it will simplify to:

```
...
elif (0 + 0) == (0 + 0):
    print('unsure')
...
```

easiest workaround would be to add another if-statement to check if there are none faces, something like this:

```
user = input()

if (user.count(":-)") + user.count(" :-) ") + user.count(":-(") + user.count(" :-( ") == 0):
    print('none')

elif (user.count(":-)") + user.count(" :-) ")) > (user.count(":-(") + user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('happy')

elif (user.count(":-)") + user.count(" :-) ")) < (user.count(":-(") + user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('sad')

elif (user.count(":-)") + user.count(" :-) ")) == (user.count(":-(") + user.count(" :-( ")):
    print('unsure')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a slightly odd combination of boolean arithmetic on integers, and integer arithmetic on booleans.

Consider:

```
if (user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) > (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")):
```

Suppose the input is `":-)"` – the if statement is equivalent to:

```
if (1 or 0) > (0 or 0):
```

`or` is a boolean operator, so the numbers are cast to booleans (`1` becomes `True`, `0` becomes `False`), so the condition is equivalent to:

```
if (True or False) > (False or False):
```

i.e. `True > False`.

Now, `>` is a numeric operator, so Python casts the booleans to numbers (`True` becomes `1`, `False` becomes `0`) and `1 > 0` so the predicate is true.  Fine.

But what if the input is `":-) :-) :-("`? Substituting in the counts, we get:

```
if (2 or 1) > (1 or 0):
```

(note here that the middle smiley is surrounded by spaces so it is [mistakenly?] counted twice)

Now, `(2 or 1)` is `True`, but `(1 or 0)` is also `True`, so `True > True` evaluates to false.

Similarly, when your final predicate is evaluated against an empty string ...

```
elif (user.count(":-)") or user.count(" :-) ")) == (user.count(":-(") or user.count(" :-( ")):
```

... this is just `(0 or 0) == (0 or 0)` i.e. `True`.

---

If you simplified the code to:

```
if user.count(":-)") > user.count(":-("):
```

and similarly for the `sad` and `unsure` cases, then you'll get the expected results.

I'm not entirely sure why want to count `" :-) "` twice – that feels like an mistake, because everything that matches `" :-) "` will also match `":-)"` – but if you wanted to combine the counts of two popular emoticons then you could just add their counts rather than using `or`, e.g.:

```
if (user.count(":-)") + user.count(":)")) > (user.count(":-(") + user.count(":(")):
```

Comment: The counting of " :-) " twice was not the intention I thought it would solve the bug somehow, I simplified it to just the characters of smiley or sad faces, the problem was at the unsure & none blocks. Thank you, you gave me insights to learn from.

Comment: Glad to help, even if it was only against some interim version of your code :-) :-) :-( :-)